# Switching between git accounts on mac

Tags: git, github-desktop

I am having two git accounts. But whenever I am doing some git operations like push, etc via command line or git desktop it is always happening from one account.

Is there a way I can configure my git such that it asks me from which git account I want to do the git operation?

Comment: Do you want to use different github accounts on the same local git repository? Or just one account for each local repository?

Comment: No I don't want to use different github accounts on the same repo. One account for each repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a git user on a per-repository basis. The repository specific configuration is called the "local" configuration and is stored in the `.git/config` file inside your repository. You can add the user configuration directly to that file or use a command-line tool. I suggest you use the tool and then read the file for educational purpose.

```
git config --local user.name "Tom Ursus Kosteran"
git config --local user.email "tuk@example.com"
```

Of course you will want to use your Github user credentials in the commands above.

Note that this configuration will remain local to your clone. It will not be pushed to any remotes. Other developers will not see your local configuration; they can define their own local configuration without any interference.

Comment: Please find more troubleshooting help here: https://help.github.com/categories/setup/

Comment: When I am cloning some repo in my local how can I specify my git account? Is there any global git config?

Comment: Note that the local git config will not be committed. You can clone a repo and add local config options without interfering with other developers. There is a global git config (global as in "for all repositories on a single machine"), but there you cannot set repository specific accounts. Does that help?

Comment: Can I modify the global git config in such a way such that it asks for my username and password whenever I try to do any git operations (like push, etc)?

Comment: No, not for "any" operations. It is possible for all operations that interact with a remote repository, though. Please explain why my answer does not suit your needs. Why do you want to enter username and password on every push instead of configuring the correct user locally for every clone?

Comment: Also, note that there is no such thing as a "git account". When git asks you for your username and password, this is because git helps you to authenticate at a remote machine. That remote machine might for example be from Github.

Comment: I am accepting your answer. I was trying to ask you how can I clone a repo by specifying username and password. I was able to find it. `git clone https://username:password@remote-repo.git`

Answer (score 1):

If we want to make git asks for username and password each time we try to do some operations on git then the below command should be used:-

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```